# What happens to sleeping threads when container shuts down?

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, concurrency

Assume

A tomcat container running a web app.

Fire a tomcat shutdown command.

In my case the tomcat container does not shutdown as there are task threads that remain after shut down command was fired.

Comment: If the container is stopped, then obviously the threads don't even exist anymore. A Java thread can't survive to its JVM.

Comment: what is happening in my case is that the threads which are sleeping are not allowing my tomcat container to stop.

Comment: that makes sense. I will try to write more precise questions next time.

Comment: @JBNizet: this does not hold true for non-daemon threads which you're delibrarely creating and managing fully yourself in JSP/Servlet code. Which is a terribly bad idea in a Java EE container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless there is magic in Tomcat that I'm not aware of (possible), the issue is probably that your sleeping threads are not daemon threads.  Once the JVM shutdown is initiated (via external HUP/INT/TERM signal, or [System.exit](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29) or whatever other means) the JVM will wait around until all non-daemon threads complete normally.  You'll need to arrange for your sleeping threads to have an orderly shutdown, or set [daemon=true](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon%28boolean%29) when they are created.